# Update GUI on variable change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I am making a space shooter and in the bottom left corner I have my stat displayed in GUI. The onGUI is I think only called when the game starts because when I change variable in a script it should change the GUI to since it gets its numbers from that script!

```
private void OnGUI()
{
    Vector2 targetPos = Vector2.zero;
    ////draw Armor
    //VitalStat armor = GetStat(StatType.Armor) as VitalStat;
    //VitalStat health = GetStat(StatType.Health) as VitalStat;
    //VitalStat shield = GetStat(StatType.Shield) as VitalStat;
    //VitalStat energy = GetStat(StatType.Energy) as VitalStat;

    if (GetComponent<Ship>() != null)
    {
        targetPos = new Vector2(95, Screen.height - 65);

        int row = 0;
        if (Armor.CurrentValue > 0)
        {
            GUIUtil.DrawBar(targetPos, 150, 15, row, Armor.CurrentValue, Armor.Value, "Armor");
        }
        else
        //draw Hp
        {
            GUIUtil.DrawBar(targetPos, 150, 15, row, Health.CurrentValue, Health.Value, "Health");
        }
        //draw Shield
        if (Shield.Value > 0)
        {
            row++;
            GUIUtil.DrawBar(targetPos, 150, 15, row, Shield.CurrentValue, Shield.Value, "Shield");
        }

        //draw energy
        if (Energy.Value > 0)
        {
            row++;
            GUIUtil.DrawBar(targetPos, 150, 15, row, Energy.CurrentValue, Energy.Value, "Energy");
        }
    }
    else if (GetComponent<Enemy>() != null)// && _hitTimer > Time.time
    {
        targetPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

        int row = 0;
        //draw Shield
        if (Shield.CurrentValue > 0)
        {
            GUIUtil.DrawBar(targetPos, row, Shield.CurrentValue, Shield.Value, "Shield");
        }
        else if (Armor.CurrentValue > 0)
        {
            GUIUtil.DrawBar(targetPos, row, Armor.CurrentValue, Armor.Value, "Armor");
        }
        else
        //draw Hp
        {
            GUIUtil.DrawBar(targetPos, row, Health.CurrentValue, Health.Value, "Health");
        }

        //draw energy
        if (Energy.Value > 0)
        {
            row++;
            GUIUtil.DrawBar(targetPos, row, Energy.CurrentValue, Energy.Value, "Energy");
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I draw my GUI.

As you can see it gets Armor.Currentvalue and when I change that number the GUI doesn't change does somebody know why or how I can fix it?

### UPDATE

This is the stat that keeps track of the health.

```
public VitalStat Health = new VitalStat() { Type = VitalStatType.Health };
```

A VitalStat has this:

```
[HideInInspector]
    public float CurrentValue;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool ShouldRegenerate = true;
    public VitalStatType Type;
    public StatType RegenerationRate;
    public StatType RegenerationStartDelay;


    private Stat _rate;
    private Stat _delay;
    private float _regenDelayTimer = 0;
```

This is how the current value gets calculated:

```
if (ShouldRegenerate && Time.time > _regenDelayTimer && _rate != null)
            {
                CurrentValue = Mathf.Min(Value, CurrentValue + (_rate.Value * Time.deltaTime));
            }
```

This is the value:

```
protected float _value;
    public virtual float Value { get { return _value; } }
```

And the value gets sets by the basevalue:

```
    public virtual void Init(StatManager statMngr)
        {
            statManager = statMngr;
    
            _value = BaseValue;
            CalculateStatValue();
        }
```

And the basevalue is set here where I change my health input:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            float intVal = Convert.ToSingle(val);
                            target.BaseValue = intVal;

                            //Safe to Database!
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Debug.Log("Invalid value " + e.Message);
                        }
                    }
```

I hope this clarify's it a little bit

Comment: _"onGUI is I think only called when the game starts"_ - no, `OnGUI` is called every frame after the scene and all of its children are drawn. This may be an issue with the value type which is common. Show some more code to clarify this. Especially code for eg. `Armor` containing it's `CurrentValue` and `Value` properties and the code that modifies these values.

Comment: @m.rogalski okey I will update the post shortly! (it is a very complicated system btw)

Comment: @m.rogalski I updated the question. Good luck!